# Adding a scroll offset to the hash target without affecting the background colour

Tags: html, css

Adding `#elementid` to a URL will scroll to the element with `id="elementid"`. I have a `position: fixed` navbar, so I need to apply an offset to the scroll position otherwise it's hidden behind the navbar. The best way I've seen to do this is to add a tall `:before` element so the browser scrolls to a bit above the element.

```
.anchor:before { 
    display: block; 
    content: " "; 
    margin-top: -100px; 
    height: 100px; 
    visibility: hidden; 
}
```

I'd also like to highlight the element by setting a background colour using the `:target` selector. The problem is the background is now much larger due to the `:before` element:

## [image]

What I'd like is this:

## [image]

This is tricky because both `:before` and `:target` need to be on the same `<h1>` with the `id`. Is it possible?

Working example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('h1, h2, h3').each(function() {
    if (this.id)
      $(this).addClass('anchor').append($('<a class="anchorlink" href="#' + this.id + '" title="link to this headline">¶</a>'));
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
  background: #888;
}
.nav {
  font-size: 40px;
  background: #444;
  color: #ddd;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
.content {
  background: white;
  padding: 12px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/* from https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/1768 */

.anchor:before {
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  margin-top: -100px;
  height: 100px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
/* from http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/yellow-fade-technique-css-animations */

:target {
  background-color: rgba(68, 180, 73, 0);
  -webkit-animation: target-fade 4s;
  animation: target-fade 4s;
}
@keyframes target-fade {
  0% {
    background-color: rgba(68, 180, 73, 0.0);
  }
  10% {
    background-color: rgba(68, 180, 73, 0.4);
  }
  100% {
    background-color: rgba(68, 180, 73, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="nav">Navbar</div>
<div class="content">
  <h1 id="t1">Title1</h1>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse in velit et nisi lobortis feugiat in dapibus odio. Quisque porttitor lacus viverra vulputate tincidunt. Curabitur cursus ex ac dolor hendrerit semper. Maecenas et urna eu lorem faucibus
  vehicula. Sed lacinia ipsum et enim consectetur, eu maximus nulla fringilla. Curabitur fermentum aliquam arcu, id luctus augue. Fusce pulvinar sapien vel finibus maximus. Morbi dignissim aliquam sem, id imperdiet magna placerat at. Vivamus placerat
  urna et ipsum viverra laoreet.

  <h1 id="t2">Title2</h1>
  Phasellus varius nunc sed mi egestas eleifend. Cras condimentum sed eros sit amet porttitor. Vestibulum hendrerit mauris feugiat venenatis vestibulum. Morbi id eleifend nibh. Nulla facilisi. Vivamus fringilla, ipsum ac iaculis hendrerit, turpis nisi gravida
  lorem, id mattis est massa vel arcu. Integer euismod eleifend tristique.

  <h1 id="t3">Title3</h1>
  In dignissim nulla nec justo egestas, vehicula rutrum orci interdum. Curabitur sed quam lobortis, maximus sem eu, accumsan metus. Sed urna quam, rutrum in posuere a, elementum nec enim. Ut pulvinar sodales ultricies. Aenean a nisi venenatis ante auctor
  sodales eget aliquet orci. Donec congue, massa a consectetur egestas, dui erat mattis massa, sit amet fringilla mauris elit eget orci. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc malesuada euismod diam,
  ut pretium metus. Phasellus ut rutrum ante. Duis ut nulla nec lacus accumsan ultrices. Nam lacinia finibus orci suscipit vulputate. In elit orci, aliquet vitae sem eu, porta gravida quam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus
  volutpat tincidunt lectus, ut laoreet lacus venenatis vel.

  <h1 id="t4">Title4</h1>
  Curabitur tristique ullamcorper augue, sit amet volutpat est placerat vel. Duis vel quam sit amet erat molestie interdum ut quis velit. Nulla iaculis luctus viverra. Phasellus vel ante elementum, posuere ante et, mattis odio. Integer tincidunt pharetra
  ex. Nullam vulputate quam varius ex laoreet ultrices. Donec condimentum, sem vitae dapibus molestie, tortor sem dictum tellus, eu tempor nisl sapien id sem. Proin dapibus tempor pulvinar. Aliquam erat volutpat.

  <h1 id="t5">Title5</h1>
  Proin dapibus, nulla molestie consequat aliquet, turpis nulla eleifend mi, nec congue felis erat nec purus. Ut a lacinia metus, at pellentesque augue. Curabitur sagittis pulvinar nisi id interdum. Mauris cursus, massa at finibus vehicula, urna eros ullamcorper
  ipsum, id convallis ipsum dolor ac enim. Sed hendrerit turpis in bibendum fringilla. Nunc a semper sapien. Proin vitae iaculis dolor. Ut placerat, libero ac vulputate dictum, velit ligula hendrerit turpis, vel aliquam felis purus eget sem. Ut ultricies
  lacinia consequat. Morbi sed ullamcorper nulla, nec placerat leo. Integer non fermentum tellus. Phasellus id lorem ex. Mauris metus turpis, elementum ac venenatis nec, finibus vitae urna.

</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using scrollTo? So when the page loads with a hashtag in the url the page loads and scrolls to the anchor with an offset defined, e.g. `.scrollTo('#anchor-5',{duration:'fast', offsetTop : '100'});`. I did almost the same recently though it was for a click event.

Comment: That works well for when the page loads and when the `hashchange` event decides to fire, but I found sometimes clicking a link wouldn't trigger the js. The `:before` method seems to be the most robust.

Comment: `.anchor:before {
  display: inline; }` instead of block will do it for you.

Comment: `display: inline` seems to remove the `:before` element entirely so the scroll offset stops work.

Answer (score 0):

CSS `background-clip` did the trick in the end. In my case there were no issues with applying the negative margin to the headings, rather than using `.anchor:before`.

```
.anchor {
    margin-top: -100px;
    padding-top: 100px;
    -moz-background-clip: content;
    -webkit-background-clip: content;
    background-clip: content-box; 
}
```

Complete example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('h1, h2, h3').each(function() {
    if (this.id)
      $(this).addClass('anchor').append($('<a class="anchorlink" href="#' + this.id + '" title="link to this headline">¶</a>'));
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
  background: #888;
}
.nav {
  font-size: 40px;
  background: #444;
  color: #ddd;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
.content {
  background: white;
  padding: 12px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/* from https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/1768 */
/*
.anchor:before {
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  margin-top: -100px;
  height: 100px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
*/

.anchor {
 margin-top: -100px;
 padding-top: 100px;
 -moz-background-clip: content;
 -webkit-background-clip: content;
 background-clip: content-box; 
}


/* from http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/yellow-fade-technique-css-animations */

:target {
  background-color: rgba(68, 180, 73, 0);
  -webkit-animation: target-fade 4s;
  animation: target-fade 4s;
}
@keyframes target-fade {
  0% {
    background-color: rgba(68, 180, 73, 0.0);
  }
  10% {
    background-color: rgba(68, 180, 73, 0.4);
  }
  100% {
    background-color: rgba(68, 180, 73, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="nav">Navbar</div>
<div class="content">
  <h1 id="t1">Title1</h1>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse in velit et nisi lobortis feugiat in dapibus odio. Quisque porttitor lacus viverra vulputate tincidunt. Curabitur cursus ex ac dolor hendrerit semper. Maecenas et urna eu lorem faucibus
  vehicula. Sed lacinia ipsum et enim consectetur, eu maximus nulla fringilla. Curabitur fermentum aliquam arcu, id luctus augue. Fusce pulvinar sapien vel finibus maximus. Morbi dignissim aliquam sem, id imperdiet magna placerat at. Vivamus placerat
  urna et ipsum viverra laoreet.

  <h1 id="t2">Title2</h1>
  Phasellus varius nunc sed mi egestas eleifend. Cras condimentum sed eros sit amet porttitor. Vestibulum hendrerit mauris feugiat venenatis vestibulum. Morbi id eleifend nibh. Nulla facilisi. Vivamus fringilla, ipsum ac iaculis hendrerit, turpis nisi gravida
  lorem, id mattis est massa vel arcu. Integer euismod eleifend tristique.

  <h1 id="t3">Title3</h1>
  In dignissim nulla nec justo egestas, vehicula rutrum orci interdum. Curabitur sed quam lobortis, maximus sem eu, accumsan metus. Sed urna quam, rutrum in posuere a, elementum nec enim. Ut pulvinar sodales ultricies. Aenean a nisi venenatis ante auctor
  sodales eget aliquet orci. Donec congue, massa a consectetur egestas, dui erat mattis massa, sit amet fringilla mauris elit eget orci. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc malesuada euismod diam,
  ut pretium metus. Phasellus ut rutrum ante. Duis ut nulla nec lacus accumsan ultrices. Nam lacinia finibus orci suscipit vulputate. In elit orci, aliquet vitae sem eu, porta gravida quam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus
  volutpat tincidunt lectus, ut laoreet lacus venenatis vel.

  <h1 id="t4">Title4</h1>
  Curabitur tristique ullamcorper augue, sit amet volutpat est placerat vel. Duis vel quam sit amet erat molestie interdum ut quis velit. Nulla iaculis luctus viverra. Phasellus vel ante elementum, posuere ante et, mattis odio. Integer tincidunt pharetra
  ex. Nullam vulputate quam varius ex laoreet ultrices. Donec condimentum, sem vitae dapibus molestie, tortor sem dictum tellus, eu tempor nisl sapien id sem. Proin dapibus tempor pulvinar. Aliquam erat volutpat.

  <h1 id="t5">Title5</h1>
  Proin dapibus, nulla molestie consequat aliquet, turpis nulla eleifend mi, nec congue felis erat nec purus. Ut a lacinia metus, at pellentesque augue. Curabitur sagittis pulvinar nisi id interdum. Mauris cursus, massa at finibus vehicula, urna eros ullamcorper
  ipsum, id convallis ipsum dolor ac enim. Sed hendrerit turpis in bibendum fringilla. Nunc a semper sapien. Proin vitae iaculis dolor. Ut placerat, libero ac vulputate dictum, velit ligula hendrerit turpis, vel aliquam felis purus eget sem. Ut ultricies
  lacinia consequat. Morbi sed ullamcorper nulla, nec placerat leo. Integer non fermentum tellus. Phasellus id lorem ex. Mauris metus turpis, elementum ac venenatis nec, finibus vitae urna.

</div>
```

*UPDATE:*

If there are `:hover` definitions on the header it will activate when hovering on the extra padding at the top. I solved this by wrapping the heading contents with a span to use `:hover` with.